# Right float width 100% doesn't work

Tags: css, html, css-float

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kasper90/GB7bs/6/
I want the main div to be as big as possible, positioned right to the toggle div.
How can I do this ? Any help is really appreciated :)

Html:

```
<div id="toggle"></div>
<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
$( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide",{ direction: "left" }, 1000 );
});
</script>
<div id="main"><object data="http://euclidthegame.com/mathexchange/5.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></div>
```

Css:

```
 #toggle {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
}
#main {
    float: right ;
    width: 100%;
    height:800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: It's working exactly the way it should, because you've set the `#main` div to `100% width`, therefore it can't fit on the top line, because `100% + 100px = more than 100%`, so it's being pushed underneath your `#toggle` div.

Comment: @NickR Okay, I see, but what I want is that it has as much width as possible without being pushed underneath. I sthat possible ?

Comment: Yep - either set the `#main` div to `width:auto` instead, or give both `divs` % width values. But note, that setting a `border` also adds to the elements total width.

Comment: If you go down the percentages route and do start adding `border` then use the [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) attribute with each element and it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this solution:

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    height:800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#toggle {
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo should use width:auto in the main container and remove the floating:right.

This should be your css:

```
#toggle {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
}
#main {
    height:800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
```

Regards

Comment: It doesn't work, look the svg image gets moved beneath the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/kasper90/GB7bs/7/

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you can get rid of the `float:right` and `width:100%` on your main div, and achieve what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/GB7bs/4/

Comment: hm.. this looked like doing the trick, but when I added the picture I wanted to add, it is like before:  http://jsfiddle.net/kasper90/GB7bs/6/

Answer (score -1):

```
#toggle {width:10%;}
#main {width:89%;}
```

Comment: This works, but if I click on the toggle div, it will hide, and in that case, I want the main div to be 100%. So I want it to get as much width as possible without being pushed underneath the toggle div.